# How to properly declare a path?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to override the CSS of a plugin called H5P on WordPress, following [their documentation](https://h5p.org/documentation/for-developers/visual-changes). I'm finding it too difficult as I'm not a developer, so I follow the steps on the first comment that suggests:

1. Create a folder named h5pmods and place it in the wp-content/plugins/ directory
2. Creating a PHP file, named **phpmods.php** that would go into the h5pmods folder, that contains:

   ```
   /**

    * H5P Mods Plugin. 

    * Alters the way the H5P plugin works.

    * @package   H5P

    * @author    Joubel <<a href="mailto:contact@joubel.com">contact@joubel.com</a>>

    * @license   MIT

    * @link      <a href="http://joubel.com">http://joubel.com</a>

    * @copyright 2015 Joubel

    *

    * @wordpress-plugin

    * Plugin Name:       H5P Mods

    * Plugin URI:        <a href="http://www.h5p.org">http://www.h5p.org</a>

    * Description:       Overrides the H5P native H5P CSS with your own adjustments.

    * Version:           0.0.1

    * Author:            H5P

    * Author URI:        <a href="http://www.h5p.org">http://www.h5p.org</a>

    * Text Domain:       h5pmods

    * License:           MIT

    * License URI:       <a href="https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT">http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT</a>

    * Domain Path:       /languages

    * GitHub Plugin URI: <a href="https://github.com/h5p/h5pmods-wordpress-plugin">https://github.com/h5p/h5pmods-wordpress-plugin</a>

    */

   // If this file is called directly, abort.

   if (!defined('WPINC')) {

     die;

   }

   /**

    * Allows you to alter which stylesheets are loaded for H5P. This is

    * useful for adding your own custom styles or replacing existing once. *

    * @param object &styles List of stylesheets that will be loaded.

    * @param array $libraries The libraries which the styles belong to.

    * @param string $embed_type Possible values are: div, iframe, external, editor.

    */

   function h5pmods_alter_styles(&$styles, $libraries, $embed_type) {

     $styles[] = (object) array(

       'path' => '/custom-h5p.css',

       'version' => '?ver=1.0' // Cache buster

     );

   }

   add_action('h5p_alter_library_styles', 'h5pmods_alter_styles', 10, 3);

   ?>
   ```
3. And a custom CSS file, named **custom-h5p.css** that would go to the /wp-content/uploads/h5p/
   directory.

The issue I'm facing is that another person says this is not optimal, and what should be done is put both files in the plugins directory, and change the path declaration in the initial php file from:

```
'path' => '/custom-h5p.css',
```

to:

```
'path' => plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'/custom-h5p.css',
```

This is where I get confused. My understanding is that `plugin_dir_url` for my case is: `htdocs/wp-content/plugins`as that's the path I found with my FTP plugin. But then I'm confused with the (*FILE*). What should I put in there? Can someone help with the exact formatting I should follow?

Also, the custom CSS file should go inside the plugin directory or inside the h5pmods folder I previously created?

The reason I don't ask in that same forum is that's very inactive.

Sorry if my question is not clear, this is so over my head I'm not even sure how to properly ask or what to look for.

Comment: You have my sympathy, Alejandro. This is why I don't use WordPress. It has bad architecture and then demands that you jump through hoops to fix the bad architecture it gives you. I have worked with web technologies for 23 years and I can't even pretend to understand the plumbing behind WordPress. And then people tell me that _"WordPress is easy"_. At my current level of understanding, I find `IndexedDB` hard but manageable. I find WordPress unfathomable.

Comment: **N.B.** You don't have to replace `__FILE__` with anything. It's one of PHP's nine `magic constants`. Leave it alone - it knows what it is supposed to be. See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: Thanks! That helps. Where do you think I should place a custom css file that targets a specific plugin, in the plugins directory or inside the plugins folder of the directory?

Comment: Also, the path  'htdocs/wp-content/plugins' makes sense?

Comment: Sadly I'm not sufficiently familiar with the WordPress folder structure to give you authoritative answers. But it looks like @VladimirCvetkovski (below) knows his way around WordPress and will be able to help you much better than I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the `custom-h5p.css` file you should place in `htdocs/wp-content/plugins/h5pmods` folder along with this `phpmods.php` file.
The magic constant `__FILE__` indicates that you specify the folder path in which the `phpmods.php` file is in. If you put `__DIR__` over there, it will output `htdocs/wp-content/plugins`.

Comment: Thanks, now I have placed both files in `htdocs/wp-content/plugins/h5pmods`, but still unsure of the correct path declaration inside phpmods.php, would this be correct?

'path' => htdocs/wp-content/plugins/h5pmods(__FILE__) ./custom-h5p.css',

Comment: just leave as is 

`'path' => plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'/custom-h5p.css'`

do not explicitly hard code the path like `htdocs/wp-content/plugins/h5pmods`

You can also check this out [https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_url/#user-contributed-notes]